# Extract a word or number using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a string which contain

```
$mystring = "------------------------
------------------------
<p>
<pre><small>
MessageID=542E7A07, Recipient=1111111111
</small></pre>
------------------------
------------------------";
```

I would like to get the MessageID and Recipient No. using the regular expression.

Comment: even when using RegExp, there are many expressions to try, it's some kind of basic RegExp skill.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I try as $result=preg_match_all("/(?<=(MessageID=))(\s\w*)/i",$mystring,$exresult);

Comment: Do you want two separate results or the entire line?

Comment: no I would like to get the messageId and Recipient on separate variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MessageID=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|Recipient=([0-9]+)
```

You can try this.Grab the matches or captures.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/2